# Is there an easy way to disable a program called virobot?

Tags: windows-7, spyware

I think is something like a management program, but I want to know what things it can do on my computer such as installing software, or remotely accessing my desktop.

I am using Windows 7 Business.

Is there an easy way to disable it?

Comment: [They have a website, which of the products for that brand are you running?](http://www.hauri.net/product/product_index.html) What have you found out so far about what it does?

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the link, I think if I understand correctly this program is used to monitor the computer and to allow "support people" to change or add or delete settings or files from the machine remotely. this program starts various windows services that can't be stopped or restarted even that my account has administrative privileges but probably my account has no more privileges than this program because is hijacking the settings for me.

Comment: Did you look in Control Panel > Programs and Features to see if you can uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a result that may help to disable virobot. Here is the link to the info [How to disable Virobot Common Scan Service](http://windowsvc.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=windowsvc&wr_id=5127&page=82).

How to disable this service.

- Open a command prompt. (Run a command prompt as Administrator in
  Windows vista/7)
- Copy command line and Paste.

***sc stop "ViRobot Common Scan Service"***

***sc config "ViRobot Common Scan Service" start= disabled***

Comment: This can also be done through the Services control panel, under Administrative Tools, if the OP is more comfortable using the GUI.

Comment: @Randolph on the services control panel all the options are disabled (stop, pause, etc.)

Comment: Ok, that's good to know.